# How to remove any interaction between AngularJS Material & the enter keypress event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Is there any way to remove the interaction between angular material components (like checkbox, select and datepicker) and the enter keypress event?

```
<md-checkbox>
    check
</md-checkbox>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRvaCZ1qQxYF6K2BaGv5?p=preview) for a real-world example.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what kind of interaction that is?

Answer (score 2):

**Prevent KeyPress on ng-keydown**

You can prevent Enter keypress with the following HTML markup :

```
<md-checkbox ng-keydown="preventEnter($event)">
   check
</md-checkbox>
```

The `preventEnter` function looks like (declared in your Controller) :

```
function preventEnter(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) { // enter keyCode
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**Custom directive to prevent Enter keypress**

If you want to do this more generally in your app, a custom directive is what your need, you can :

```
app.directive('myPreventEnter', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
};
```

and then all your inputs are :

```
<md-checkbox my-prevent-enter>...</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is very similar to @segito10.
I'm looking for a more general solution. I mean one that can be applied to all form inputs (md-select, datepicker...).

Comment: using a directive (ng-keydown or a custom one) is more "Angularish" than using DOM

Comment: I agree with you. What i'm meant by a general solution is avoiding ng-keydown on every input. Imagine a form with lots of inputs. This way we have to use ng-keydown on every one of them.

Comment: just added an example of a custom directive in order to do this properly

Answer (score 1):

Add an EventListener and pevent for the default event if keyCode==13

```
var checks = [...document.getElementsByTagName("md-checkbox")];
checks.forEach(function(c){
    c.addEventListener("keydown",
        function(e) { 
            if(e.keyCode === 13) e.preventDefault();
        }, 
    false);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SwsQMGMnxXerxvCaIYLG?p=preview

Comment: thank you @segito10. Your solution was very helpful. But in the case the checkbox is inside a form, calling e.preventDefault() will disable form submission. Any suggestions?

Comment: no the submission event is not disabled , i mean no when you blur on the element so in the if statement you can add  **this.blur();** i have updated the plnkr you can try to submit the form by pressing enter on the input

Comment: what if i want to submit the form after checking the checkbox (input text not focused).

Comment: is it possible to write a directive when applied to a form will:
- prevent checking the checkbox (or opening a datepicker...)
- submit the form

Comment: then change **this.blur()** by **document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();**

yes it is possible all do you have to do is catch the event then trigger submit form after doing your stuff

Comment: I tried your solution document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
the form is submitted (checks.lenght) time and
the page is refreshed (this is not the angular way)